# Java pattern matching on children of a parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, pattern-matching, overriding

I have a `Parent` class and a child class that `extends Parent` called `Child`. I have a method `run` which can take either a `Parent` or `Child` instance. I create a `Child` instance using the code `Parent child = new Child()`. See code below.

I want the code to output "You are a child", but instead I receive "You are a parent". I understand the reasoning behind this, however I was wondering what I could use to make the `Child` implementation of `run` to execute.

In my system I will have multiple "child" classes that inherit from `Parent` and multiple `run` methods that cater for each "child" class. As a result, casting will not work and so if you include casting in your solution, I'm afraid it will not help me. My inspiration for this is more or less derived from pattern matching in a language such as Haskell.

```java
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent child = new Child();
        run(child);
    }

    public static void run(Child child) {
        System.out.println("You are a child");
    }

    public static void run(Parent parent) {
        System.out.println("You are a parent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation of which method to call is part of compilation.  In your code, you store the `new Child` as a `Parent` variable, so from the compiler's perspective, all it knows is you have a `Parent`, hence it resolves the call to that method.

If you want 'You are a child' to display, you'd either need to declare the variable as a `Child`, or have one method that does some runtime check on the type (something like `if (item instanceof Child) { ... }`).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the static-methods. Add the methods to your objects and overwrite them.

```
class Parent {

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("You are a parent");
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("You are a child");
   }
}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent child = new Child();
        child.run(); // <- prints "you are a child"
    }
}
```

Prove: https://ideone.com/v1Ijhy